# jdbc output plugin logstash using UPSERT function

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, logstash

I'm using [this](https://github.com/theangryangel/logstash-output-jdbc) plugin as output for my logstash logs.

I need to use the upsert function to check if a row exists then update, if it doesn't exist then simply add.

I'm using PostgreSQL as db and it supports the usage of UPSERT, very good described [here](https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/upsert-records-with-postgresql-9-5). As input, the logs are coming from elasticsearch.

The problem with my configuration is that I correctly add new rows in my table but cannot update an existing one.

Here's my configuration :

```
jdbc {
        driver_jar_path => '/home/vittorio/Downloads/postgresql-42.1.1.jre6.jar'
        connection_test => false
        connection_string => 'jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres'
statement => ["

        INSERT INTO userstate VALUES(?,?,?,?,?) on conflict (username)
        do update set (business_name, iban, status, timestamp) = ('%{[resource][response_attributes][business_name]}','%{[resource][response_attributes][iban]}','%{[resource][response_attributes][status]}','%{@timestamp}')
        where userstate.username = '%{[request][username]}';", "%{[request][username]}","%{[resource][response_attributes][business_name]}","%{[resource][response_attributes][iban]}","%{[resource][response_attributes][status]}","%{@timestamp}"
        ]
 username => "myuser"
 password => "mypass"
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

I manged to make it work by myself and this is what I've done so far :

```
  jdbc {
          driver_jar_path => '/home/vittorio/Downloads/postgresql-42.1.1.jre6.jar'
          connection_test => false
          connection_string => 'jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres'
          statement => ["

          INSERT INTO userstate VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)
          on conflict (username)
          do update set (business_name, iban, status, timestamp) = (?,?,?,?)
          where userstate.username = ?"
          , "%{[request][username]}","%{[resource][response_attributes][business_name]}","%{[resource][response_attributes][iban]}","%{[resource][response_attributes][status]}","%{@timestamp}","%{[resource][response_attributes][business_name]}","%{[resource][response_attributes][iban]}","%{[resource][response_attributes][status]}","%{@timestamp}","%{[request][username]}"

          ]
          username => "myusername"
          password => "mypass"

      }
```

Basically,I've changed the `where` statement using `?` instead of `%{[request][username]}` and then map each `?` with the corresponding value from the log. I know, it's pretty long stuff after the coma but this is the only way I found to make it work. If anyone knows a better way to do it please let me know.

Thank you